# Passive of the verb 'contain'

Tags: passive-voice

We may use the verb 'contain' in a passive sentence? Question is, how? To me, the verb 'contain' is kind of INTRANSITIVE since it presents a state, not an action i.e. there is no working force (agent) in the sentence made with 'contain'.

Look:

The room has a few chairs. (can't be changed into passive)

The room contains a few chairs. What will be passive?

A few chairs are contained by the room.

OR

A few chairs are contained in the room.

OR

A few chairs are contained within the room.

Comment: @user070221 yes, but partially.

Comment: As a general rule, if you can add *by something* (or *in something*) to a sentence, then it's in the passive voice.